# Can I separate schemas by tags in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

In FastAPI you can add tags to endpoints and give yourself nice 'folders' in swagger, like this:
[image: example of tags]
But can I do the same with schemas? They all in the same block (pic below), and, truth be told, that`s not very easy to use. Is there a way to separate them in different blocks?
[image: chemas example]

Comment: It's actually a feature of swagger to categorize different endpoints based on tags and not the FastAPI. What you want though is actually not possible; not to my knowledge at least.

Comment: I understand that this is the feature of swagger, but I hoped may be there's some additional tweaks in FastAPI. If this operation is not possible that's very frustrating and very odd in my perspective - if you have option to categorize paths, why not schemas?  Thanks for your comment, I'll try not spend too much time on this now